# UIPageViewController direction of paging

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

I have got the mistake connected with direction of paging. I am developing an application such as iBooks, but this one have to support direction of paging from left to right. This application is intended one for reading arabic books.

I have used the `Private API(CAFilter)` for it, but the application has not passed appstore's review.

I created `pageViewController` and changed his parameter of direction.I will rewrite the application using

```
UIPageViewController."direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse"
pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
[pageViewController setViewControllers:controllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The direction was changed, wasn't it? But my book is still paged from Right to Left. Why?

Comment: See the post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11124807/400909

Answer (score 0):

*//[Constants getCurrentLan] bool returns if ur app's language is in arabic
//if arabic, set ur spine location to max*

```
NSDictionary *options = [Constants getCurrentLan] ? [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax] forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey] : nil;


self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl                                                                navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];
```