# RTL languages uipageviewcontroller animation

Tags: iphone, ios5, uipageviewcontroller, right-to-left

I know this question is typique and it was asked many times in the forum, but I still cannot solve my problem, so please if any body can help be that would be GREAT :)

I am creating a book application in the arabic languages and I need to perform the transitions of the uipageviewcontroller from right to left. And thats all I have to say.

One more thing (if I hadn't explain very well my self) I have the exact need as this thread: [How to change UIPageViewController direction of paging curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705332/how-to-change-uipageviewcontroller-direction-of-paging-curl-animation) but I couldn't manage to make the solution they spoke about, so if someone can explain me or give me a link where I can have how to do it that would be more than enough :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done in this way

1. Swap the code of pageViewController's datasource from `viewControllerBeforeViewController` to `viewControllerAfterViewController`
2. Change `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin` to `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax`

To check that, start Page-Based Application template as Universal and change the following in `ModelController.m`

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageData count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

and change `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin` to `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax` and swipe the condition of (indexOfCurrentViewController % 2 == 0) in "RootViewController.m"

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)) {
        UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

        self.pageViewController.doubleSided = NO;
        return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMax;
    }

    DataViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

    NSUInteger indexOfCurrentViewController = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:currentViewController];
    if (indexOfCurrentViewController == 0 || indexOfCurrentViewController % 2 == 0) {
        UIViewController *previousViewController = [self.modelController pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousViewController, currentViewController, nil];
    } else {
        UIViewController *nextViewController = [self.modelController pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentViewController, nextViewController, nil];
    }
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];


    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}
```

Source: [PageViewControllers Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW14)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've found this some time ago already but I was bit lazy to put it in the forum, but off course I would have done it one day or another :)

Answer (score 1):

You should dive into core graphics and core animation.

1. Make 2 layers (a previous/next and current)
2. When doing a 'pangesture' (see the [Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) ) you need to see if it's a swipe left or swipe right (previous/next page)
3. Then perform a 3D Rotation on the layer(s)

here's a nice [example](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper) about flipping pages

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I saw the link about the example and its a very interesting indeed, but it isn't what I need, I can used it next time for a ipad development, but what I need for the moment is to inverse the same animation effect for the uipageviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Madev, Do you not want to use the "PageBased Application" template?

Simply start a new xCode Project:

Under iOS > Application , look for Page-Based Application. Hit Okay, Choose you Options. All you have to do is supply your content (via the "DataSource").

Now that is the complicated part...But here's some tips

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_a_Page_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_UIPageViewController

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

Comment: Thanks lawrence fletcher, yes thats the effect I wanted also I used the same techotopia link to realize my application, but what I need is to move forward in the inverse direction, like when reading an RTL language book, hope I could explain what I need :S

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `semanticContentAttribute` on your UIPageViewController's viewDidLoad like:

```
if <You app language is Arabic/RTL based> {
  self.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
}else {
  self.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
}
```

Keep coding......... :)