# UIPageViewController: Reverse .scroll animation direction for right-to-left languages

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, right-to-left

Is it possible to reverse the animation direction for `UIPageViewController` for right-to-left languages when using `UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle.scroll`?

Swiping left and right works inverts correctly for right-to-left, but my next button solution animates in the wrong direction (animates like it does for left-to-right).

My current solution to do so is to set `pageControl.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`, and to inverse the `viewModels` so that index 0 for right-to-left is the last index (`viewModels.count - 1`), as well as inverting the animation direction + `viewControllerBefore`/`viewControllerAfter`, e.g.:

- `viewControllerBefore` becomes: `nextIndex = isRightToLeft ? vc.index - 1 : vc.index + 1`(and vice-versa for `viewControllerAfter`)
- `nextTapped`'s `inDirection` parameter for `transitionFrom` changes to `isRightToLeft ? .reverse : .forward`
- Change `loadFirstPage` to set the `startIndex` to `numberOfPages - 1` (aka `viewModels.count - 1`) rather than 0
- Reverse the view models so index 0 is `viewModels.count - 1` (in `init`):

  ```swift
       if isRightToLeft {
           viewModels = viewModels.map({ viewModel in
               ViewModel(index: (numberOfPages - viewModel.index - 1), text: viewModel.text, color: viewModel.color)
           }).reversed()
  ```

But I would like a solution that simply changes the animation direction out-of-the-box, like it seems to be possible when changing the `spineLocation` for `UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle.pageCurl`, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124807/16873617) states.

##### Animations

Note that for the `How it is by default` the page comes from the right, but the page control indicator moves in the opposite (expected) direction.

| How it is by default | Expected Functionality |
| --- | --- |
| [image: current functionality] | [image] |

##### Default Implementation:

```swift
import UIKit

struct ViewModel {
    var index: Int
    var text: String
    var color: UIColor
}

class DummyViewController : UIViewController {
    let label = UILabel()
    
    let vm: ViewModel
    
    let index: Int
    
    init(vm: ViewModel) {
        self.vm = vm
        self.index = vm.index
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
    
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = vm.color
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.textColor = .black
        label.text = vm.text
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        self.view = view
    }
}

class ViewController : UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    
    let nextButton = UIButton()
    
    var isRightToLeft: Bool {
        traitCollection.layoutDirection == .rightToLeft
    }
    
    var currentIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex
        }
    }
    
    var numberOfPages: Int { return viewModels.count }
    
    var viewModels: [ViewModel] = [
        ViewModel(index: 0, text: "First", color: .red),
        ViewModel(index: 1, text: "Second", color: .blue),
        ViewModel(index: 2, text: "Third", color: .green),
    ]
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self
        
        pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        
        nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
        nextButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        addChild(pageViewController)
        
        pageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        view.addSubview(nextButton)
        
        view.subviews.forEach { $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pageViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            pageControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nextButton.centerYAnchor),
            
            nextButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextTapped), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        loadFirstPage()
    }
    
    func loadFirstPage() {
        let startIndex: Int
        startIndex = 0
        
        guard let start = viewControllerAtIndex(startIndex) else {
            return
        }
        
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([start], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func transitionFrom(index: Int, inDirection direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection) {
        let nextIndex = direction == .forward ? index + 1 : index - 1
        
        guard let next = viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex) else {
            return
        }
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([next], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: { finished in
            self.pageViewController(self.pageViewController, didFinishAnimating: finished, previousViewControllers: [], transitionCompleted: finished)
        })
    }
    
    func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> DummyViewController? {
        guard index >= 0 && index < numberOfPages  else { return nil }
        let viewModel = viewModels[index]
        return DummyViewController(vm: viewModel)
    }
    
    @objc
    func nextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard currentIndex < numberOfPages - 1 else {
            print("ending because \(currentIndex)")
            return
        }
        
        let direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = .forward
        transitionFrom(index: currentIndex, inDirection: direction)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vc = viewController as? DummyViewController else { return nil }
        let nextIndex: Int = vc.index - 1
        return viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vc = viewController as? DummyViewController else { return nil }
        let nextIndex: Int = vc.index + 1
        return viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        guard let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? DummyViewController else { return }
        currentIndex = viewController.index // Update currentIndex, which updates pageControl.currentPage
    }
}
```

##### Manual reversing to support right-to-left (solution I'm trying to avoid).

Excluded `ViewModel` and `DummyViewController` as they're unchanged.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    
    let nextButton = UIButton()
    
    var isRightToLeft: Bool {
        traitCollection.layoutDirection == .rightToLeft
    }
    
    var currentIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex
        }
    }
    
    var numberOfPages: Int {
        return viewModels.count
    }
    
    var viewModels: [ViewModel] = [
        ViewModel(index: 0, text: "First", color: .red),
        ViewModel(index: 1, text: "Second", color: .blue),
        ViewModel(index: 2, text: "Third", color: .green),
    ]
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self
        
        pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        
        pageControl.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        
        nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
        nextButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        
        if isRightToLeft { // HERE
            viewModels = viewModels.map({ viewModel in
                ViewModel(index: (numberOfPages - viewModel.index - 1), text: viewModel.text, color: viewModel.color)
            }).reversed()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        addChild(pageViewController)
        
        pageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        view.addSubview(nextButton)
        
        view.subviews.forEach { $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pageViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            pageViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            pageControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nextButton.centerYAnchor),
            
            nextButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextTapped), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        loadFirstPage()
    }
    
    func loadFirstPage() {
        let startIndex: Int
        if isRightToLeft { // HERE
            startIndex = numberOfPages - 1
            currentIndex = startIndex
        } else {
            startIndex = 0
        }
        
        guard let start = viewControllerAtIndex(startIndex) else {
            return
        }
        
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([start], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func transitionFrom(index: Int, inDirection direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection) { // UNCHANGED
        let nextIndex = direction == .forward ? index + 1 : index - 1
        
        guard let next = viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex) else {
            return
        }
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([next], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: { finished in
            self.pageViewController(self.pageViewController, didFinishAnimating: finished, previousViewControllers: [], transitionCompleted: finished)
        })
    }
    
    func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> DummyViewController? {
        guard index >= 0 && index < numberOfPages  else { return nil }
        let viewModel = viewModels[index]
        return DummyViewController(vm: vm)
    }
    
    @objc
    func nextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard (currentIndex < numberOfPages - 1 && !isRightToLeft) || (currentIndex > 0 && isRightToLeft) else { // HERE
            return
        }
        let direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = isRightToLeft ? .reverse : .forward // HERE
        transitionFrom(index: currentIndex, inDirection: direction)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vc = viewController as? DummyViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let nextIndex: Int
        if isRightToLeft { // HERE
            nextIndex = vc.index + 1
        } else {
            nextIndex = vc.index - 1
        }
        
        return viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vc = viewController as? DummyViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let nextIndex: Int
        if isRightToLeft { // HERE
            nextIndex = vc.index - 1
        } else {
            nextIndex = vc.index + 1
        }
        
        return viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        guard let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? DummyViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        currentIndex = viewController.index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is *much* simpler than I realized - setting the `direction` simply changes the *animation* direction, it doesn't change what index/view controller is going to be presented.

As such, the solution is simply changing `transitionFrom` to:

```swift
    func transitionTo(nextIndex: Int, inDirection direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection) {
        // Removed the `next` setting here in favor of getting it passed from `nextTapped`
        guard let next = viewControllerAtIndex(nextIndex) else {
            return
        }
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([next], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: { finished in
            self.pageViewController(self.pageViewController, didFinishAnimating: finished, previousViewControllers: [], transitionCompleted: finished)
        })
    }
```

and changing `nextTapped` to:

```swift
    @objc
    func nextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard currentIndex < numberOfPages - 1 else { return }
        
        let direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = isRightToLeft ? .reverse : .forward // This is key
        transitionTo(nextIndex: currentIndex + 1, inDirection: direction)
    }
```

#### Alternate, less intrusive solution

Alternatively, a less intrusive solution would be to subclass `UIPageViewController` and simply flip the animation direction if we're in a right-to-left locale.

```swift
private extension UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection {
    var flipped: Self {
        switch self {
        case .forward:
            return .reverse
        case .reverse:
            return .forward
        @unknown default:
            return .reverse
        }
    }
}

class LocalizedPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    override func setViewControllers(
        _ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?,
        direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection,
        animated: Bool,
        completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil
    ) {
        let isRTL = view.effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft
        let direction = isRTL ? direction.flipped : direction
        super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Then I would simply need to change my initialization of the `UIPageViewController` to `LocalizedPageViewController`, and no other changes are needed!